# How to count two different columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, heidisql

I have a database which looks like this.

```
school
  exam
    firstname: varchar(40)
    name: varchar(40)
    lesson: varchar(30)
    item: smallint(6)
  lessons
    lesson: varchar(30)
    grade: smallint(6)
    abc: char(1)
    edate: date
  students
    firstname: varchar(40)
    name: varchar(40)
    grade: smallint(6)
    abc: char(1)
```

My task is to get the columns of dates, number of exams on that date, number of students who write an exam on that date. Something like Date - Exam Count - Student Count. I have done this but in two different queries.

```
SELECT l.edate, COUNT(l.edate) AS Exams
FROM lessons l
WHERE (l.edate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY l.edate
ORDER BY l.edate DESC
```

`Result:
edate       Exams |
==================|
2020-05-24 |   1  |
2020-05-23 |   1  |
2020-05-22 |   2  |
2020-05-20 |   1  |
2020-05-19 |   1  |
2020-05-18 |   1  |
2020-05-16 |   2  |
2020-05-15 |   2  |
2020-05-14 |   5  |
==================|`

```
SELECT l.edate, COUNT(l.edate) AS Writing
FROM lessons l
JOIN students s
ON (l.abc = s.abc) AND (l.grade = s.grade)
WHERE (l.edate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY l.edate
ORDER BY l.edate DESC
```

`Result:
edate       Writing |
====================|
2020-05-24 |    23  |
2020-05-23 |    27  |
2020-05-22 |    40  |
2020-05-20 |    30  |
2020-05-19 |    27  |
2020-05-18 |    25  |
2020-05-16 |    52  |
2020-05-15 |    34  |
2020-05-14 |   116  |
====================|`

After I tried to combine these two queries into one and I got this, but it gives me the same count at every row, see the image below:

[image]

I know that's because of adding new table, but how do I make it work?

```
SELECT l.edate, COUNT(l.edate) AS Exams, COUNT(s.firstname) AS Writing
FROM lessons l
JOIN students s
ON (l.abc = s.abc) AND (l.grade = s.grade)
WHERE (l.edate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY l.edate
ORDER BY l.edate DESC
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and add sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. Do **not** use images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. Just combine your two queries:

```
SELECT E.edate, Exams, Writings FROM
(
  SELECT l.edate, COUNT(l.edate) AS Exams
  FROM lessons l
  WHERE (l.edate IS NOT NULL)
  GROUP BY l.edate) As E
JOIN
(
  SELECT l.edate, COUNT(l.edate) AS Writings
  FROM lessons l
  JOIN students s
  ON (l.abc = s.abc) AND (l.grade = s.grade)
  WHERE (l.edate IS NOT NULL)
  GROUP BY l.edate) As W ON E.edate=W.edate
ORDER BY E.edate
```

NOTE: Not tested, no MySQL on current box

Comment: Thanks, everything works fine, except there is mistake in `SELECT E.edate, Exams, Writings FROM`: `Writings` -> `Writing`, but that nothing.

Comment: @Anonymous228 Fixed nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `count(distinct)`.  However, your tables don't seem to have unique ids, so my best guess is:

```
SELECT l.edate, COUNT(*) AS Exams, COUNT(DISTINCT s.firstname) AS Writing
FROM lessons l JOIN
     students s
     ON l.abc = s.abc AND l.grade = s.grade
WHERE l.edate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY l.edate
ORDER BY l.edate DESC
```